# Bash : Remove forward slashes in filenames and folder names

Tags: macos, bash, rename, file-rename

I need to remove forward slashes in all filenames and folder names starting from a given folder, and including all its subfolders.

For use with automator on Mac, I have found the bash script below. It works when trying to replace any type of character (using for instance [A] to replace A in filenames) , but does not work with the forward slash.

```
#!/bin/bash
find "/startdir/" -depth -name "*[\/]*" |     
while read FILEDIR 
do
    DIR="${FILEDIR%/*}"   
    FILE="${FILEDIR/*\/}"        
    NEWFILE="${FILE//[\/]/_}"
    mv "$DIR/$FILE" "$DIR/$NEWFILE"
done
```

Any help very welcome!

Comment: why the filename should contain a forward slash? anyhow I've executed your script in my bash test env and I've got this message: find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name '*[\\/]*'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-same
file'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ '*[\\/]*''.

Comment: @123 Mac OS != linux

Comment: @Groelk Put an `echo` in front of the `mv` and see what it's actually doing (if it even makes it into the loop). Doing `bash -x` might also be useful.

Comment: @BroSlow Yep my bad.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. This is meant to process the contents of whole hard drives on Mac. I am looking for a script - any script - that could process recursively all the names of folders, subfolders and files to remove slashes. As unfortunately the forward slash character is supported on OSX in filenames and folder names.

Comment: @ClaudioM -wholename and -same file did not work either. But the script works perfectly with "-same file" when replacing any character other than the forward slash. Couldn't make the grep command work.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer over here:
https://superuser.com/questions/617517/remove-all-illegal-characters-from-all-filenames-in-a-given-folder

The forward slash should be replaced by semi-colons in the bash script to match the forward slash character in OSX filenames.
And with this change the above script works.